TYPO3 XML instead of Template
I have this method
public function feedAction()
    {
        $articles = $this->getArticles();
        $this->view->assign('articles', $articles);
        $this->view->setTemplatePathAndFilename('EXT:Extension/Resources/Private/Templates/Feed/xml.html');
        return $this->responseFactory->createResponse()
            ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8')
            ->withBody($this->streamFactory->createStream($this->view->render()));
    }

this code gives me the complete html structure and then my template code. I just want xml code. how can i remove the templates etc.

Use PropagateResponseException similar to this example: https://brotkrueml.dev/extbase-controller-action-responses-in-typo3/#c120
